# Modern proof of Goldwasser-Sipser IP[n]=AM[n+2]?

Tags: complexity-theory, interactive-proof-systems

The [original paper](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Ejyc/710/Goldwasser-Sipser.pdf) by Goldwasser and Sipser proved IP[Q(n)]=AM[Q(n)+2].
Is there some modern source that proofs the theorem? (The full theorem and not specific cases such as limiting the number of rounds to 2.)

Comment: What do you mean by "modern"?  A proof that was valid in 1600 remains valid today.  What's wrong with the proof in that paper?  Do you have some specific criteria?

Comment: I'm looking for an adaptation of the original paper. Something written in modern notation and may be used for a seminar work. I looked for scribes of complexity courses but didn't find one that proved the full theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Appendix F.2.1. of Oded Goldreich's book here: [https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/CC/r6.pdf](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Eoded/CC/r6.pdf)